# How do I query a firebase firestore sub-collection for additional properties, using Angular/Ionic and Stripe Extension

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using Angular/Ionic with Firestore and Stripe's Firebase Extension for Subscriptions. I have added products to the backend of Stripe which then populates Firestore with a products collection and a pricing sub-collection. There are multiple prices available on each product. I am trying to query the products and the pricing in order to display the products available for purchase on a checkout page. I can get the products but I have not been able to get the prices for each product. The differences in pricing for each product are time based(single, monthly, yearly).
The following is how Stripe describes the process on the github page for the stripe extension at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-subscriptions/POSTINSTALL.md
List available products and prices
Products and pricing information are normal collections and docs in your Cloud Firestore and can be queried as such:

```
db.collection('${param:PRODUCTS_COLLECTION}')
  .where('active', '==', true)
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(async function (doc) {
      console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      const priceSnap = await doc.ref.collection('prices').get();
      priceSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
    });
  });
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
const prodRef = this.afs
   .collection<Product>('products', (ref) => ref.where('active', '==', true));

this.products = prodRef.valueChanges();

this.prices = await prodRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
   map((actions) => {
     actions.map((a) => {
       const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
       data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
       return data;
     });
   })
 );
 // this.pricing = await prodRef.valueChanges().toPromise().then((querySnapshot) => {
 //   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
 //     console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
 //     const priceSnap = snapshotChanges collection('prices').get();
 //     priceSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => doc.data())
 //   })
 // })
 
 // snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
 //      actions.map(a => {
 //       const data = a.payload.doc.data();
 //       const id = a.payload.doc.id;
 //       return { id, ...data };
 //     });
 //   }));
```

Comment: The query you shared from the documentation does exactly what you want to achieve so I am a bit confused on what is the issue you are facing. Why have you not used that code? Can you described what the issue is in more details?

Comment: The first code block is the example provided on the docs for the Stripe extension but it is not using typescript syntax. I need to know how to write the same query using typescript. The second code block are my attempts at it.